# dplyr::select() working alone, but errors when used with other functions

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to select columns in my dataframe to mutate() and pivot_longer(). select() works when I use it by itself, but does not work when it is used inside mutate() or pivot_longer().

Example:

```
n = 20
test <- tibble(
  a = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  b = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  c = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "1" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "2" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "3" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "4" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  grp = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)
)


# Using select() alone:
test |>  select(-matches("^[0-9]"))

> A tibble: 20 × 4
>        a     b     c   grp
>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
>  1     4     1     1     1
>  2     3     5     2     3
>  3     1     5     5     1
>  4     5     2     4     2
>  5     3     2     3     3
>  6     2     2     5     1
>  7     2     5     2     3
>  8     3     4     1     1
>  9     4     1     3     1
> 10     1     2     4     2
> 11     2     3     3     1
> 12     3     5     2     1
> 13     2     2     4     3
> 14     5     5     2     2
> 15     2     3     1     1
> 16     4     5     4     3
> 17     1     3     1     1
> 18     1     1     4     3
> 19     4     3     5     1
> 20     5     5     4     2


# Using select() within functions
test |> mutate(across(select(-matches("^[0-9]")), as.factor))
test |> pivot_longer(select(matches("^[0-9]")), names_to = "Numbers", values_to = "Sample")

# Both give this error:
> error in `UseMethod()`:
> no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these two examples you just don't need `select`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
n = 20
test <- tibble(
  a = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  b = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  c = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "1" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "2" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "3" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  "4" = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  grp = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)
)

test |> mutate(across(-matches("^[0-9]"), as.factor))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 8
#>    a     b     c       `1`   `2`   `3`   `4` grp  
#>    <fct> <fct> <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct>
#>  1 5     5     3         2     1     1     1 3    
#>  2 5     4     5         2     5     5     4 2    
#>  3 1     4     1         2     1     4     4 1    
#>  4 3     3     2         2     3     2     5 3    
#>  5 2     5     2         1     4     2     1 3    
#>  6 5     2     3         3     5     3     3 2    
#>  7 3     4     1         2     3     5     1 3    
#>  8 5     2     1         5     2     2     4 1    
#>  9 5     5     4         5     5     3     1 1    
#> 10 4     4     1         4     1     1     5 2    
#> 11 4     1     5         4     1     5     1 3    
#> 12 1     1     2         1     4     5     2 1    
#> 13 2     2     4         5     2     1     1 1    
#> 14 5     1     2         1     3     2     4 2    
#> 15 2     2     1         1     2     5     4 2    
#> 16 3     2     3         5     1     4     5 3    
#> 17 2     2     5         4     3     2     4 1    
#> 18 5     2     5         2     1     4     1 2    
#> 19 4     4     2         3     1     3     5 3    
#> 20 1     1     5         4     5     4     2 1
test |> pivot_longer(matches("^[0-9]"), names_to = "Numbers", values_to = "Sample")
#> # A tibble: 80 × 6
#>        a     b     c   grp Numbers Sample
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>    <int>
#>  1     5     5     3     3 1            2
#>  2     5     5     3     3 2            1
#>  3     5     5     3     3 3            1
#>  4     5     5     3     3 4            1
#>  5     5     4     5     2 1            2
#>  6     5     4     5     2 2            5
#>  7     5     4     5     2 3            5
#>  8     5     4     5     2 4            4
#>  9     1     4     1     1 1            2
#> 10     1     4     1     1 2            1
#> # ℹ 70 more rows
```

The arguments passed to `select`, `mutate` and `pivot_` are all `tidy-select` expressions, so they're all on the same level. `select` says "keep these [tidy]selected columns". This means that any function you use to `select` columns to keep is translated the same way. `mutate(across())` takes it to mean "do function on these [tidy]selected columns" and `pivot_longer` to mean "[tidy]select these columns to pivot".